# How to implement REST API security by validating user's role and functions allowed for the user using spring security in a Spring Boot project

Tags: spring, rest

//  I have the following API security implementation for resteasy

Sample API with custom annotation OperatorFunctionAllowed

```
@Path
@PUT
@OperatorFunctionAllowed(value = {OperatorFunctionEnum.MANAGE_CONFIGURATION})
public Collection<AnalyzerParameterSupportDTO> updateParameterSupport(){}
```

Inside The Filter class there is logic to

1) check if a API has annotation of OperatorFunctionAllowed

2) Then checks what kind of operation is allowed on that API(in this case it is 
MANAGE_CONFIGURATION from the above mentioned API.

3) later checks if the logged in user is allowed to perform that operation

```
public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext)
{
    ResourceMethodInvoker methodInvoker = (ResourceMethodInvoker) requestContext.getProperty("org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker");      
    Method method = methodInvoker.getMethod();

    //Only intercept calls to endpoints that required some specific permission
    if(isAnnotationPresent(OperatorFunctionAllowed.class, method))
    {
        SessionVO sessionVO = SessionServiceImpl.getCurrentSession(httpRequest);
        if(sessionVO == null)
        {
            throw new DashboardException(DashboardErrorsEnum.NO_SESSION_STARTED, Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED);
        }

        Set<OperatorFunctionEnum> functionsSet = null;
        OperatorFunctionAllowed operatorFunctionAnnotation = getOperatorFunctionAllowedAnnotation(method);
        if (operatorFunctionAnnotation.value().length > 0)
        {
            functionsSet = EnumSet.copyOf(Arrays.asList(operatorFunctionAnnotation.value()));
            if(!isUserAllowed(functionsSet))
            {
                throw new DashboardException(DashboardErrorsEnum.ACCESS_UNAUTHORIZED, Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED);
            }
        }
    }
}

private boolean isUserAllowed(final Set<OperatorFunctionEnum> neededFunctions) 
{
    Set<OperatorFunctionEnum> currentPermissions = SessionServiceImpl.getCurrentPermissions();
    for (OperatorFunctionEnum function : neededFunctions)
    {
        if (currentPermissions.contains(function))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

private boolean isAnnotationPresent (Class<? extends Annotation> annotationClass, Method method) {
    return method.isAnnotationPresent(annotationClass) || method.getDeclaringClass().isAnnotationPresent(annotationClass);
}

private OperatorFunctionAllowed getOperatorFunctionAllowedAnnotation(Method method) {
    Class<?> clazz = method.getDeclaringClass();
    if (method.isAnnotationPresent(OperatorFunctionAllowed.class)) {
        return method.getAnnotation(OperatorFunctionAllowed.class);
    } else if (clazz.isAnnotationPresent(OperatorFunctionAllowed.class)) {
        return clazz.getAnnotation(OperatorFunctionAllowed.class);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I am trying to implement API security in Spring Boot project, can someone help me with an example on how to implement using spring security